# Hive throws ORC does not support type conversion from file type error when create table as select with to_json UDF

Tags: exception, hive

With following simple SQL:

```sql
ADD JAR ivy://com.klout:brickhouse:0.6.+?transitive=false;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION to_json AS 'brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF'; 

create table test (b boolean);
insert into table test values (true);
create test1 as select to_json(b) as b from test;
```

I got the following exception.

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:332)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:177)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:171)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:251)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.SchemaEvolution$IllegalEvolutionException: ORC does not support type conversion from file type boolean (1) to reader type string (1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.SchemaEvolution.buildConversionFileTypesArray(SchemaEvolution.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.SchemaEvolution.buildConversionFileTypesArray(SchemaEvolution.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.SchemaEvolution.<init>(SchemaEvolution.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.<init>(RecordReaderImpl.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.rowsOptions(ReaderImpl.java:550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.createReaderFromFile(OrcInputFormat.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.<init>(OrcInputFormat.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getRecordReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1067)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:67)
        ... 16 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

Answer (score 0):

After days' struggle, I figured out this issue is: `to_json(b) as b`.
As I use the same column name after it's converted to a string with to_json. Seems Hive will use the original table schema to derive column type for the new table. And when we store a different type into that column, it throws an exception. What a wired behavior.